# Jquery jerky scrolling

Tags: jquery, animation, position

I have this method which scrolls a left menu up and down the screen:

```
$window.scroll(function () {

    var windowScroll = $window.scrollTop();
    var sideMenuOffset = $sidebar.offset();
    var scrollInArticle = Math.max(windowScroll - tutOffsetTop, 0);
    if (scrollInArticle > tutHeight) {
        scrollInArticle = tutHeight;
    }
    var percentageThrough = scrollInArticle / tutHeight;

    $sidebar.offset({ top: Math.max(windowScroll - (percentageThrough * 100), menuStartTop), left: sideMenuOffset.left });

});
```

It works smoothly about 90% of the time, but it does appear quite jerky every now and then (viewing on a good desktop with Chrome).

Any solutions on how we can make this a lot smoother?

Comment: Can you create a demo on jsFiddle?